# Understanding Tkinter.Frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem about analyzing these lines of code, if you want to view the whole code I can post it.

Can you guys please explain whats going on here?

I'm planning to create a database program with tkinter and sqlite, I have a windows PC.

I didnt write the code I just want to study it.

```py
class meh(Tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.initialize_user_interface()
```

Whats going on here?

```
def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
```

Comment: This isn't tkinter specific, it's how all python objects work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python supports [object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) programming. One of the core concepts in OOP is inheritance, which means that a class can "inherit" methods from another class. For instance

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name):  # The __init__ function is called when an object is
        self.name = name       # instantiated. That's called a "constructor"
        print('Created ' + name)
    def make_sound(self):
        print("...")
    def die(self):
        print(self.name + ' died.')


class Cat(Animal):          # The class in the parenthesis is the superclass.
    def make_sound(self):   # A cat makes a different sound from any other animal,
        print("Meow")       # so we give it its own make_sound method. But it dies
                            # the same as any other animal, so it will inherit
                            # the die method from the superclass.
```

Now when we try this code:

```
>>> fluffy = Animal('Fluffy')
Created Fluffy
>>> fluffy.make_sound()
...
>>> fluffy.die()
Fluffy died.

>>> kitty = Cat("Kitty")
Created Kitty
>>> kitty.make_sound()
Meow
>>> kitty.die()
Kitty died.
```

So now, let's look at the code you gave:

```
class meh(Tkinter.Frame):
```

This line creates a class that inherits from `Tkinter.Frame`. That means that it should be able to do anything that a Frame can do, which will probably be things like containing UI elements.

```
def __init__(self, parent):
```

This is a constructor that gets called when you create a new `meh`. It takes `parent` as a parameter. I'd check the documentation, but in UI development, that often means interface element that this one should appear inside. For instance, the parent might be a window or another frame.

```
Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
```

This is calling the `__init__` method of the class `Tkinter.Frame`. This basically means that instead of defining something to do instead of what `Tkinter.Frame` does in its constructor, they're defining things to do *in addition* to `Tkinter.Frame.__init__`.

Comment: thanks for the answer moira, i will digest this info tomorrow because i am really exhausted mentally 90% of my brain cells  are dead ive been trying to understand classes and object for 12 hours now i just want to rest thank you :)